# SQL Server Remote Access Error

Tags: sql-server

Installed SQL Server 2014 Enterprise version on two computers, trying to remotely access the database in one of the computers through the other.

Getting this error message:

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while established a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or accessible. Verify that instance name is correct and SQL Server is allowed to connect through remote connection (provider:-namedpipeprovider, error:-40, could not open a connection to SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server, error-2)

From my online research, I did the following things

1. Checked if SQL Server and browser service is running.
2. Changed the port numbers in the windows firewall for inbound/outbound connections
3. Enabled TCP/IP ports

Not sure how to rectify the error, please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by making sure you can ping the server. That will tell you if it is a problem seeing the computer or a problem with the connection.

Comment: After pinging, try `telnet <server name or IP address> 1433`.

Comment: Thank you Sean,I'm not sure how to do it.Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer in this post. it's pretty in-depth as to what all needs to be setup correctly. By default SLQ Server is pretty well locked down for local access only.

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer but +1 anyway because that is a good thread on the topic. :)

Comment: Thanks Mike,I looked into it.when i run sqlcmd -L.its showing a blank screen.not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL server from another computer, You might need 2 more steps:

1. Change port numbers in the firewall is not enough, make sure that you have **enabled TCP/IP connections** in **SQL
   Server Configuration Manager**
2. [Configure SQL Server to listen on the specific port that you need](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.110).aspx).